# Remove the fitting from the <p> tags

Tags: html, css

I have five `<p>` tags like this:

```
<p align="center" class="menu">Home</p>
<p align="center" class="menu">Store</p>
<p align="center" class="menu">Composition</p>
<p align="center" class="menu">Feedback</p>
<p align="center" class="menu">Contacts</p>
```

with some css code like this:

```
.menu { 
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: roboto;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 background:white;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
```

The problem is that when I resize the window of the browser or I open the page on my phone the `<p>` tags fit to page. How can i fix them to the page so they don't fit?

EDIT
when the window is completely extended:
[image]

when i resize the window:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "fit"?

Comment: when the window is completely extended there are five tags in one line but if the window is smaller the <p> tags makes two line (3 tag in the first line and 2 tag in the second line).

Comment: If the page width is narrow enough, the `p` elements will wrap onto a second (or more) line as needed.  In such a case, what you you like to happen? Do you want all the `p` elements to keep on one line, even if it means that the width is less then 200px?

Comment: @MarcAudet yes i want all p in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **max-width** and not width: 200px.

then you can adjust padding better like so (note: I like ems):

```
 .menu { 
     font-size: 1em;
     font-family: roboto;
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     display: inline-block;
     background:white;
     max-width: 200px;
     position: relative;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 1em .6em
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want `p` to fit in the window, use `width: 20%` instead of `width: 200px`. This would make each item occupy a fifth of the length of the window.

Comment: `text-align:center` doesn't work with `display:inline-block`

Comment: There's width, so it would.

Comment: hmm...yep! forgot that

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;
```

if you want to fix the positions of `<p>` tag